# Compiling C files with sublime text 3

Tags: c, windows, gcc, sublimetext3

I started learning C for my studies, and I'd like to use Sublime Text 3 to compile those files. I've been using CodeBlocks before, but I'm already using Sublime Text for LaTeX and Python.

I've downloaded the gcc.exe file, saved in C:\Program Files\WinBuilds\bin and added it to the Path.

I've created a new build system:

```
{   
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

I get the following output:

```
cc1.exe: fatal error: Files/WinBuilds/WinBuilds/include: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['gcc', 'Rect.c', '-o', 'Rect']]
[dir: C:\Users\Matthieu KUNTZ\Desktop\Rectangle]
[path: C:\Program Files\Python3.4.3\;C:\Program Files\Python3.4.3\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\WinBuilds\bin]
```

What should I do to be able to compile and run simple C files ?

Comment: You can't just grab the `gcc.exe` and put it wherever you like. You need to properly install whole `gcc` build chain (compiler, linker, headers, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc has a whole installation that comes with it. Just the gcc.exe won't do you any good. Take the steps outlined [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html) to find out how to exactly install the complete package. Install it to the directory your gcc.exe is currently in, then your compiling should work.

If you do not install gcc properly, the exe wont know where to find all the things a complete-solution compiler needs to function (linker, header files, scripts, auxillary files, etc).

Comment: Thanks ! I started from scratch again, and it worked perfectly !